# Tramp: how to add (-A) agent forwarding to ssh connections?

Tags: tramp, ssh

I'm using Magit over Tramp and my git push commands fail because tramp doesn't forward my ssh-agent to the remote machine.

In pseudo code, it looks like I need to do the following:

```
tramp-methods["ssh"][tramp-login-args].prepend( ("-A") )
```

How do I do this without copy/pasting the entire `tramp-methods` variable into my emacs init file? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Check the [Association-Lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) section of the elisp manual.

Comment: @npostavs: Thanks for the hint. Is there a better way to code "put something in list if not already there"?

Comment: You could also use `~/.ssh/config` to deal to this (from specific hosts) regardless of whether or not you're using Emacs to connect, by setting `ForwardAgent yes` for the host(s) in question.

Comment: @phils: I probably should taken this approach form the start. I don't really like maintaining ssh_config files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Tramp 2.2.13, you will be able to overwrite entries of `tramp-methods`. In your case, you would do something like

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-connection-properties
             (list (regexp-quote "/ssh:user@randomhost.your.domain:")
                   "login-args"
                   '(("-A") ("-l" "%u") ("-p" "%p") ("%c")
                     ("-e" "none") ("%h"))))
```

Tramp 2.2.13 is integrated in the upcoming Emacs 25.1. Tramp 2.2.13 will be released itself at the end of this year. For the time being, you could use the development versions of Emacs or Tramp, of course.

Comment: Will you be able to modify the existing args or simply replace? One of the reasons I took the modify approach was so I wouldn't have to worry about stepping on future changes to tramp.

Comment: It's not a modification or a replace, it is just a kind of overlay. `tramp-methods` keeps untouched. Settings in `tramp-connection-properties` are prioritized over `tramp-methods`. But you are right, likely there shall be a convenience function which returns the recent value of a given argument in `tramp-methods`; this would ease it to change. Will think about.

Comment: In what file should this be added?

Comment: In your init file, after loading Tramp.

Answer (score 6):

After suggestions...

```lisp
(defun add-ssh-agent-to-tramp ()
  (cl-pushnew '("-A")
              (cadr (assoc 'tramp-login-args
                           ; if on Windows using Putty with Pageant,
                           ; replace "ssh" with "plink"
                           (assoc "ssh" tramp-methods)))
              :test #'equal))
(add-ssh-agent-to-tramp)
```

Comment: This did it for me. can now multi hop into ec2 instance in private subnet. Thankyou!